# Appending a div with a class based on checkbox state

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio, sitecore

I have a checkbox in admin in Sitecore. How can I append a `hidden-xs` class to a custom div if the box is checked? Can jQuery's append be avoided or not?

Comment: You should at least show us how you are rendering your output...

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb you should always show some code from your attempts. This way YOU will learn, and it's a lot easier for us to understand and locate your problems.

When that's said, I have no knowledge about Sitecore, but since you've marked your question with jQuery I think you should look into [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).

That way you can do something like:

```
if($("#yourCheckBox").is(':checked'))
    $("#yourElementToShowOrHide").addClass("hidden-xs");  // checked
else
    $("#yourElementToShowOrHide").removeClass("hidden-xs");  // unchecked
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. check state of your input.

```
if ($('input.yourclassofInput').is(':checked')) {
$(".ClassOfDivToHide").addClass("hidden-xs");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking how to add a class to a div based on a checkbox field of a Sitecore item, this is the way to go:

```
var field = (CheckboxField)item.Fields["name of your checkbox field"];
if (field.Checked)
{
...  // add class to your div (can't elaborate on this as we don't know how you are rendering the output)
}
```

where "item" is the item containing the field. This is just some quick code with no data checks to get you going.